# minecraft crashes on osx

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I just bought minecraft and every time i run it , it crashes. When i double click on its icon in the application folder nothing happens so i have to go into the contents folder to launch its jar file. After I login this is the crash report that keeps displaying.

I am running this on osx 10.8.2 (mountain lion)
My specs are:

2.26 ghz intel core 2 duo, 8gb ram

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Surprise! Haha. Well, this is awkward.

Time: 2/25/13 5:29 PM
Description: Failed to start game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not get the JAWT interface
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndInitHandle(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.access$100(AWTSurfaceLock.java:49)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock$1.run(AWTSurfaceLock.java:89)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.privilegedLockAndInitHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:86)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndGetHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:64)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXCanvasPeerInfo.initHandle(MacOSXCanvasPeerInfo.java:53)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplayPeerInfo.doLockAndInitHandle(MacOSXDisplayPeerInfo.java:56)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.PeerInfo.lockAndGetHandle(PeerInfo.java:85)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXContextImplementation.create(MacOSXContextImplementation.java:47)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Context.<init>(Context.java:120)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:858)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:784)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:765)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:232)
    at asq.a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:515)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.4.7
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.8.2
    Java Version: 1.7.0_10, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 55114328 bytes (52 MB) / 85721088 bytes (81 MB) up to 1271398400 bytes (1212 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    LWJGL: 2.4.2
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1525442-help-minecraft-crashes-could-not-get-the-jawt-interface/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of LWJGL (Lightweight Java Game Library) that comes bundled with Minecraft is incompatible with the version of Java that you have installed.

- If you have multiple versions installed, you can use Java Preferences (usually at `/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app`) to change your system's default Java version.
- You can upgrade [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) without too much difficult - download the most recent version and put it in your ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/ folder, overwriting the old files and the natives folder.
- If you don't want to upgrade LWJGL, you can downgrade Java until Minecraft works. Oracle maintains links to old versions on their site, though versions that are outdated enough will require signing up for an Oracle account before they'll give you the download link. [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_jre_32/history/) and [OldVersion](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/java-platform/) can help with that.

Comment: do you know where i can download an older version of java? i cant seem to find it anywhere

Comment: Downgrading Java is an EXTREMELY bad idea - it opens your computer up to a variety of virus attacks, none of which you want :P Upgrading LWJGL is simple - just download the newest version and install it into the minecraft folder, replacing the current lwjgl files.

Comment: @Andrew And yet it is a functioning option that some people may prefer, especially if they're on a secure network or using an operating system like *Mac OS* that is nearly never the target of viruses, Java-based or otherwise. There's a reason why the conditional "if downgrading Java is undesirable..." is deliberately included. (I'd dispute the "extremely" part too, but that's not an argument I want to get into the details of.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Mac OS is definitely not *never* the target of viruses, it's just less common. Java-based viruses often work on both Macs and PCs equally, I think it was unclear that that might often be undesirable. I might swap your second and third answers, unless you object.

Comment: @Andrew Swapping them doesn't change the intent, and I do see the editorial difference, so that's fine!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is when you open the launcher, select Options => Force Update